# JavaScript inline event listeners...do they wait for JS to load?

Tags: javascript, load

I normally work with jQuery as it's convenient to use the document ready feature so I can wait until the DOM is ready before attaching event listeners to DOM elements.

I've inherited a project that, at least for a while, is going to be using a lot of inline event calls:

```
<element onclick="doThis()">
```

Not pretty, but what I have to work with.

Normally I'd load the JS file at the bottom of the HTML page. However, if I do that in this case, does the event wait until the document is ready (body load) to try an execute, or will that onclick event fire as soon as the element is clicked regardless of whether or not that big JS file has loaded yet?

I think the latter happens, meaning that in this situation, I can't be moving my JS file out of the HEAD for now. But wanted to confirm.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "attribute". It's an HTML attribute.

Comment: You are correct. Maybe I should call it 'attribute javascript call'? just sounds weird, though. I've always thought of 'onclick' as an event. and the 'onclick' attribute is 'listening' for said event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event handling attribute on an HTML element is like a mini script block which is evaluated independently of other script blocks on the page. In the case of onclick="", as soon as the element is read into the DOM, the event handler attribute has been evaluated and will attempt to run if the element is clicked.

You can think of those attributes, by the way, as functions. The code between the double quotes of the attribute definition is the same as the code between the curly braces of a function definition.

```
onclick="/* IN HERE */"
```

is the same as

```
elem.onclick= function(){/* IN HERE */};
```

The function is defined upon being evaluated by the browser, and executed upon click.

If anything provides for the code in the `/* IN HERE */` area and has not been loaded into the DOM by the time the element makes it into the DOM, clicking *will* cause an error.

As I said, all script blocks and inline handlers are evaluated separately. So your scenario of clicking is the same as follows:

```
<!-- same as firing the click event -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    doSomething();
</script>
<!-- externally loaded script file--late! -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/provides_doSomething.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, good explanation. Thanks! (more ammo for me to convince a rewrite and/or switch to jQuery! ;)

Comment: Changing to jQuery won't make the page load faster, it will just add another big chunk of script to your page that *still* must be loaded before any code will run correctly. Moving script from the head to the foot doesn't make the page load any faster, it just means the page is visible sooner (depending on the size of the script and whether it's been cached or not). If you are looking for a "DOM ready" function, you can implement that fairly simply without using a library.

Answer (score 1):

yep. when you click, the onclick event will fire even while your javascript scripts is loading. it will append the function call to the queue and when your script isn't loaded yet, it would result to an error. 
so maybe you can add bit in your code to check if its loaded:

```
<element onclick="if (doThis) {doThis();}">
```

Comment: in that situation, what would the 'if' be checking for?...whether or not the external JS file has loaded yet? (if so, I think it'd be as much work to just move all of these inline calls out and attach them when the dom is read. ;)

Comment: it would check whether there's a function or any object named doThis.

Comment: BTW, there's no need for the braces: `onclick="if (doThis) doThis();"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The user won't be able to click the element before the DOM is ready.

Comment: So, does that mean ALL javascript calls, regardless of whether or not they are inline wait for the entire DOM to be ready (which includes the loading of all external JS files?)

Comment: No, decidely not - that's why we need things like jQuery's `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely misread the answer. You're saying they won't be able to click because it will throw an error, right?

Comment: the user can click the DOM as soon as it's ready. but the function called by the element may not be ready yet.

Comment: @DA: not that it'll throw an error - if the DOM isn't ready, how could the user possibly interact with the page in any way?

Comment: @danniel, yes, that's my understanding as well. @matt, I'm not quite following you. this is an inline event lister on an element. Once that specific element is loaded onto the page (regardless of the rest of the DOM) wouldn't it try to fire that function if I clicked on it?